# How do I compare two arrays of objects to see if they have the same ids and then return another value from the matching object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So here are two sample arrays:

`const sample1 = [{id: '1', name: 'jon', quantity: '5'}, {id: '2', name: 'sue', quantity: '4'}, {id: '3', name: 'greg', quantity: '7'}];`

`const sample2 = [{id: '1', dish: 'cheesecake'}, {id: '2', dish: 'carrot cake'}, {id: '3', dish: 'cupcake'}];`

I would like to write a function to compare the ids from `sample1` with the ids of `sample2`. If the ids match I need to return the `dish` value from sample2. I tried mapping sample1 and using `find()` inside the loop on sample2 but could not get it to work.

Comment: can you show the code which not working?

Comment: what would your expected result look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), filter the objects and map the wanted property.

```js
const
    sample1 = [{ id: '1', name: 'jon', quantity: '5' }, { id: '2', name: 'sue', quantity: '4' }, { id: '3', name: 'greg', quantity: '7' }],
    sample2 = [{ id: '1', dish: 'cheesecake' }, { id: '2', dish: 'carrot cake' }, { id: '3', dish: 'cupcake' }],
    set1 = new Set(sample1.map(({ id }) => id)),
    result = sample2
        .filter(({ id }) => set1.has(id))
        .map(({ dish }) => dish);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all sample2 dishes that have a matching id in sample1, the following code does the trick.

```
const sample1 = [{id: '1', name: 'jon', quantity: '5'}, {id: '2', name: 'sue', quantity: '4'}, {id: '3', name: 'greg', quantity: '7'}];

const sample2 = [{id: '1', dish: 'cheesecake'}, {id: '2', dish: 'carrot cake'}, {id: '3', dish: 'cupcake'}];

// Array with all Sample2 dishes that have a matching id in Sample1
const result = sample2
  .filter(sample2Entry => sample1.some(sample1Entry => sample1Entry.id === sample2Entry.id))
  .map(sample2Entry => sample2Entry.dish);
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to combine the two based on the id you can do it like this:

```js
const sample1 = [{id: '1', name: 'jon', quantity: '5'}, {id: '2', name: 'sue', quantity: '4'}, {id: '3', name: 'greg', quantity: '7'}];

const sample2 = [{id: '1', dish: 'cheesecake'}, {id: '2', dish: 'carrot cake'}, {id: '3', dish: 'cupcake'}];
  
const result = sample1.map(s1item => ({
  ...s1item,
  dish: sample2.find(s2item => s2item.id === s1item.id) ? sample2.find(s2item => s2item.id === s1item.id).dish : null
}))
  
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could firstly `.map()` your `sample1` array to an array of `ids`. You can then build a look up table from your `sample2` array which associates an array of dishes with an id key. Then using the array you made initially using `.map()`, you can `.flatMap()` over that array to get all your dishes for each given user:

```js
const sample1 = [{id: '1', name: 'jon', quantity: '5'}, {id: '2', name: 'sue', quantity: '4'}, {id: '3', name: 'greg', quantity: '7'}];
const sample2 = [{id: '1', dish: 'cheesecake'}, {id: '2', dish: 'carrot cake'}, {id: '3', dish: 'cupcake'}];

const sampe1map = sample1.map(({id}) => id);
const lut = sample2.reduce((acc, {id, dish}) => {
  acc[id] = [...(acc[id] || []), dish];
  return acc;
}, {});
const res = sampe1map.flatMap(x => lut[x]);

console.log(res);
```

If your `ids` in `sample2` can be unique, you can use `.map()` instead of `.flatMap()` with a `new Map()` instead for your look up table:

```js
const sample1 = [{id: '1', name: 'jon', quantity: '5'}, {id: '2', name: 'sue', quantity: '4'}, {id: '3', name: 'greg', quantity: '7'}];
const sample2 = [{id: '1', dish: 'cheesecake'}, {id: '2', dish: 'carrot cake'}, {id: '3', dish: 'cupcake'}];

const sampe1map = sample1.map(({id}) => id);
const lut = new Map(sample2.map(({id, dish}) => [id, dish]));
const res = sampe1map.map(x => lut.get(x));

console.log(res);
```